# OData Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, etl

I've been having this weird issue with SSIS Odata connection.

My organization trying to move data from sharepoint lists into SQL Server and with Odata connection, sharepoint REST API I've succeeded to establish the connection and preview data are showed up without any problem.

Here's the weird part, when I'm trying to execute the package it shows me error in Odata connection.

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OData Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F.
```

Googled it and found articles which more or less saying the same thing with DNS problem, tried to change my DNS to google DNS and it worked well. The problem is I need to deploy my pipeline into server and there's no way I can use google DNS on company server.

Also tried

- Changing run 32/64 bit
- whitelisting organization domain in hosts file but only succeeded in connection and failed on the execution

  127.0.0.1 msoid.[organization_name].onmicrosoft.com

  127.0.0.1 msoid.onmicrosoft.com
- Changing https into http

Is there anyone know what's going on or what SSIS try to authenticate here so I can tell the network guys to whitelist it?

Comment: If you have a re-encrypting proxy appliance on your corporate network, such as one from BlueCoat Systems Inc (though there are plenty of others now), you may need to ask your network administrators to add the target domain name(s) to the proxy's "allow list." It could be prompting for proxy authentication credentials which the OData Connection will be unable to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to this and am not finding clear answers. Running Windows 10 with .NET 4.8. I solved by enforcing strong encryption with these Registry Key additions:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:32
```

As specified at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/tls-issue-with-ssis-package-while-accessing-odata-source-like-dynamics-ax-online