# SSIS - OData Connection problem every 6th day

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl

I have a scheduled JOB (SSIS package) that loads data from Sharepoint Online list using OData Connection.
It works from IDE and after deploy it works on the server for 5 days. After that I get the following error message: "Error: ... failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F."
I make a new deploy and it works again for 5 days.
Our environment: SQL Server 2016 Standard on FCI cluster.

[image: OData connection]

TLS 1.2 enforced - no effect
Force Encryption enabled - no effect
I tried to put the password in a variable or project parameter - no effect

Comment: Try the advice given in the comment to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66881933

Comment: Thank you Roger. It is true that the error message is the same, but the actual error is not. It works for me for 5 days after deploy, only then I get this error. To fix the error I just need to redeploy, I don't need to change anything in the package.
I am not aware of any proxy or firewall errors. The necessary addresses are already in the exception list.